# Read String From Serial port Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

```vb
Imports System.IO.Ports 
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form4
    Dim myStringBuilder As String
    Dim insert As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Public user As String

Private Sub Serialport2_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort2.DataReceived
    myStringBuilder = SerialPort2.ReadExisting()
    Me.Invoke(New EventHandler(AddressOf UpdateControls))
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateControls(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim A As String = myStringBuilder
    Dim Sqql As String

    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        cnn.Open()
    End If

    insert.Connection = cnn


    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Sqql = "SELECT * FROM `FileInfo` WHERE `File ID`='" & A & "'"
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(Sqql, cnn)
    cmd.Fill(dt)
    Dim i As Integer = dt.Rows.Count
    Dim todaysdate As String = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now)
    If i = 1 Then
            insert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `File Log`(File ID,Name,Information,Time,Date) " & _
                " VALUES('" & A & "','" & dt.Rows(0).Item("Name") & "','" & user & " telah" & dt.Rows(0).Item("Status") & "File" & "','" &
_
                TimeOfDay & "','" & todaysdate & "')"
            textBox1.Text += dt.Rows(0).Item("Name") & "   " & TimeOfDay & "   " & todaysdate & 

Environment.NewLine
            textBox1.Select(textBox1.TextLength, 0)
            textBox1.ScrollToCaret()
            insert.ExecuteNonQuery()
            myStringBuilder = ""
        Else
            myStringBuilder = ""
            textBox1.Text += A & Environment.NewLine
        End If


End Sub


Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    cnn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\data.mdb"

    If SerialPort2 IsNot Nothing Then
        SerialPort2.Close()
    End If

    SerialPort2 = My.Computer.Ports.OpenSerialPort("COM27", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One)
    textBox1.Text = "-- Door Have Open -- " & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine


End Sub

Private Sub textBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles textBox1.TextChanged

End Sub End Class
```

in my serial monitor view it will appear correctly but in visual basic it will auto break line and not display the string in one line.
I Tried other method like serialport.readline() but nothing happen.

Comment: ReadExisting() is the problem.  You usually get only one or two characters.  You need to get the full response first.  Like using ReadLine() instead, as long as the device helps and sends a specific character to indicate the end-of-line.  A linefeed is standard.

Comment: thanks for the reply . so , what should i change? . im kind new to this program.

Comment: You must read the full response before you call Me.Invoke().  What that takes is impossible to guess from the question, you didn't describe what the device sends at all.  If you have no idea then ReadLine() is worth a shot.

Comment: if im using readline command . it wont invoke , and when i try to stop or close the port , this error will come out . The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request. im using RS232 to read RFID CARD and im using PIC 16F877A to read and send data to serial com.

Comment: okay. thank you. i thought the problem from vb code . because it will display correctly in serial monitor view

Answer (score 0):

If you are having issues with extracting data from your serial port you could try this:

```
Sub SerialPort_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)

    Dim currentSP As SerialPort = Convert.ChangeType(sender, GetType(SerialPort))
    Dim strBuilder As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder()

    For index = 1 To currentSP.BytesToRead        
        strBuilder.Append(Convert.ChangeType(currentSP.ReadByte(), GetType(Char)))
    Next

    ' Have a global string to allow the threads to have a shared resource
    myString = strBuilder.ToString()

    Me.Invoke(New EventHandler(AddressOf UpdateControls))

End Sub
```

It should work the same way as the `SerialPort.ReadLine()`, this approach also lets you manipulate the data however you want. Instead of working with a string you could always work the data like this:

```
Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(currentSP.BytesToRead) {}
buffer(index) = Convert.ChangeType(currentSP.ReadByte(), GetType(Byte))
```

So instead of appending the `Char` to the `String` you can add the `Byte` to the buffer

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim str As String = MyCOMPort.ReadExisting()
If Me.InvokeRequired Then
    Me.Invoke(New dlUpdateText(AddressOf updatetext), str)
Else
   updatetext(str)
End If
```